# What are the helper functions available in javascript to copy all properties from an object to another?

Tags: javascript, object, helper

What are the helper functions available in javascript to copy all properties from one object to another?

I believe we can copy all properties from one object to another by using simply a "for" loop.

But are there any other methods available which we can just chain to an object and achieve the goal?

Comment: What do you mean by a helper function? Are you referring to a prototype function, such as `foo = {a:1}.extend({b:2})`?

Comment: There is no any such functionality available in javascript. Rather you can do it using JQuery or any other javascript library.  using JQuery you can make a copy of object like this var copy = $.extend(true, {}, object)

Comment: [`Object.create(srcProtoObject)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) will create a *new* object which "chains" the old object. However this is *not* the same as [recursively] copying the properties of an object.

Comment: @Quantas: Yes, I was referring to a prototype function.

Comment: @user2864740: I believe Object.create(srcProtoObject) will copy all properties from srcProtoObject recursively.Right?

Comment: @SubratRout No, `srcProtoObject` simply becomes the `__proto__` of the new object. The second argument to `create` takes in an object representing property descriptors; not properties/values.